# Why is the return type of std::bind unspecified?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, bind

The return type of `boost::bind` and now `std::bind` is unspecified.

[unspecified bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935401/unspecified-bind)

[What is the return type of boost::bind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412065/what-is-the-return-type-of-boostbind)

Why is it that the return type of `boost::bind` and now `std::bind` is unspecified? Why isn't it something like `boost::function` and `std::function`?

I realize that the intent is to refer to the return type via type deduction but that doesn't answer why `std::bind` is special.

If that was just the whim of the committee then ok, there's not much else to say, but is there a technical reason that specifying a return type for `std::bind` is uniquely burdensome or that not specifying it permits a more efficient implementation?

Comment: I had always assumed the return type was something akin to `bound_type<func_type,ret_type,params...>`, but I never checked to confirm this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, for starters there isn't just one return type.  It varies greatly depending on the types of the arguments passed in.

The C++ Standard is leaving a lot of flexibility to implementers exactly how different cases are broken out (using overloading and SFINAE) and mapped onto different closure object types.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't boost::function or std::function because those both perform type erasure, which may need a memory allocation (bind does not) and typically cannot have the function call inlined.